# Error while deploying Tabular model from localhost to a different server

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have been experiencing a problem when deploying Tabular model from my local machine to a different server (Server X). The error message I am getting is this one:

[image]

Basically what I am doing is creating new Import from **Server (Tabular) Project** on my local machine, importing model from a different server (image below:)

[image]

making some changes on it, then againg deploying on that Server X:

[image]

But after all this, after I try to deploy I get this error.

The things I have tried:

- In my data source under **Edit Permissions** -> **Credentials** -> **Edit** -> I have tried every single credential combination inside **Impersonation Mode**, **Windows**, **Database** and **Microsoft Account** that I have (the company I work in has multiple different accounts for SQL jobs, tasks etc.), I have tried every account and password tha I have, but the error remains.
- I have also checked if I was an Administrator for Analysis Services Tabular (explained [here](https://sqlkover.com/not-an-administrator-for-analysis-services-tabular/)), and I was (my account is Administrator).
- I have also checked if my Windows user is under Administrators, and it is.
- I have also checked which server roles are assigned to my SQL login, and all of them are:

  [image]

Judging by all this, I should be able to deploy Tabular model from local machine to Server X, is there something I'm missing? Or I should be doing everything on Server X, without doing anything on my local machine?

The Visual Studio version I'm using is 2019.

Comment: You are logged in using your domain account?  Can you connect from  your workstation to the SSAS server using SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a model, you have to be either an Analysis Services administrator on Server X or a Windows Server administrator on Server X.

You say you checked if you are an admin on Analysis Services, but didn't show a screen shot, so let's confirm this.

- Open SSMS
- Connect to **Analysis Services** (**NOT** Database Engine). I think you might have picked the wrong thing here.
  [image]
- Right click the server and choose **Properties**
  [image]
- Click the **Security** page. (Note that the window says **Analysis Server Properties**)
  [image]

Your domain account should be here. Be 100% sure that the account you see listed here is the account that you are using on your computer that is running Visual Studio/SSDT. Based on the message you are getting, this is where the problem should be.

The only other option is for your domain account that you are using to be a Windows admin on Server X. All Windows admins are automatically Analysis Services admins, though they will not show up on the list above. The link you referenced is how a Windows admin can add themselves as an Analysis Services admin if they are not on the list.

Things that don't matter for the message you are getting:

- Data source credentials
- Whether you are an Administrator on your local computer or running VS with elevation
- Server roles assigned to SQL Server (database engine). Analysis Services is completely separate from the database engine and those login properties in your screen shot.

Developing on your local machine is the way to go. Don't change that. You just need to get the permissions on Analysis Services correct.